# sound pool sound effect

Tags: android, eclipse, soundpool

i have a guitar sound
load on sound pool
know i want to do some sound effect Fx like Echo on it.
is there any classes to doing it ??
i am using sound pool because its faster for a guitar app and media player is not fast enouth.

```
this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    sp1 = new SoundPool(7, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundID = sp1.load(this, R.raw.st1_c1, 1);

public int S1f8_c1() {pk=18;return  mS1f8 = sp1.play(soundID, vl, vl, 1, 0, S1f8);}
```

Comment: As far as I know, you would not get very far with soundpool and effects like an echo. But with that said maybe you can try to use a handler.postAtTime inside a for loop with a constant int to keep track of playback for the echo. Once it plays the first time in the loop the handler will play the next sounds at the appropriate time and with each iteration you can set the volume of the soundpool object a little lower to create the effect. It might work that way.